# Ajuda verificação

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-eventos

Estou com fazendo um cadastro que e preciso que **verificação** imprima um erro caso alguma das opções seja alterada.
**Meu codigo:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#concluir").validate({
        rules:{
            usuario: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 14,
                nowhitespace: true,
                alphanumeric: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            senha: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 14
            },
            rsenha: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#senhaa"
            },
            nome: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 14,
                nowhitespace: true,
                alphanumeric: true
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                alert("Cadastrado com Sucesso!")
                form.submit()
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Cara, tenta ser mais claro na sua pergunta, especificar o que está fazendo e informar um código que dê para realizar os testes.

Comment: O que é isso ? Nunca vi esse tipo de pergunta '-'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando houver uma alteração no select com o name="pacoteinicial" irá executar um callback, no meu exemplo foi o console.log()

sobre a função [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
$('body').on('change', "select[name='pacoteinicial']", function(){
    console.log('Erro: select alterado!');
});
```

Comment: Ideal seria esclarecer o que você fez e porque. Só soltar códigos aqui sem explicações não vai, efetivamente, resolver a questão.

Comment: Resposta alterada, obrigado pela sugestão!

Comment: Resolvido, obrigado!